# How to map a DataSource Resource Ref Name to JNDI Name in EJB 2.x in WildFly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

How to map a DataSource Resource Ref Name to a JNDI Name in EJB in WildFly?

I know that in JBoss 4.2.3 it is done in `jboss.xml` but it is not working in WildFly.

Here is my test:

I am working with Java 1.7, XDoclet 1.2.3, WildFly 8.2.1.Final, Dynamic Web Module 2.5, EJB 2.1 in Eclipse Luna.

In WildFly I have a DataSource named `SchedulerDS` whose JNDI name is `java:jboss/datasources/SchedulerDS`. It is using jTDS JDBC Driver and connecting to a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

In Eclipse I created these projects:

1. an Enterprise Application project named Z01_EAR.
2. a Dynamic Web Project named Z01_WAR.
3. a EJB Project named Z01_EJB.
4. a EJB Client Project named Z01_EJBClient.

In Z01_EJB project, I create a XDoclet Stateless Session Bean (EJB 2.1) named `SLS01`. In it I define a DataSource Resource Ref named `jdbc/chumbo`. And I define its mapping to JNDI Name `java:jboss/datasources/SchedulerDS`.

This is the `ejb-jar.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
   <description><![CDATA[Z01_EJB generated by eclipse wtp xdoclet extension.]]></description>
   <display-name>Z01_EJB</display-name>
   <enterprise-beans>
      <session id="Session_SLS01">
         <description><![CDATA[An EJB named SLS01]]></description>
         <display-name>SLS01</display-name>
         <ejb-name>SLS01</ejb-name>
         <home>com.z01.ejb.SLS01Home</home>
         <remote>com.z01.ejb.SLS01</remote>
         <local-home>com.z01.ejb.SLS01LocalHome</local-home>
         <local>com.z01.ejb.SLS01Local</local>
         <ejb-class>com.z01.ejb.SLS01Session</ejb-class>
         <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
         <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
         <resource-ref id="ResRef_1">
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/chumbo</res-ref-name>
            <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
            <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
         </resource-ref>
      </session>
   </enterprise-beans>
   <assembly-descriptor id="AssemblyDescriptor_1">
   </assembly-descriptor>
   <ejb-client-jar>Z01_EJBClient.jar</ejb-client-jar>
</ejb-jar>
```

This is the `jboss.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS 4.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss_4_0.dtd">
<jboss>
   <enterprise-beans>
      <session>
         <ejb-name>SLS01</ejb-name>
         <jndi-name>SLS01</jndi-name>
         <local-jndi-name>SLS01Local</local-jndi-name>
         <resource-ref>
            <res-ref-name>jdbc/chumbo</res-ref-name>
            <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/SchedulerDS</jndi-name>
         </resource-ref>
        <method-attributes>
        </method-attributes>
      </session>
   </enterprise-beans>
   <assembly-descriptor>
   </assembly-descriptor>
   <resource-managers>
   </resource-managers>
</jboss>
```

In EJB I wrote a method to test

```
public void testRetrieve() {

    String dataSourceLookupString = null;
    InitialContext initialContext = null;
    DataSource dataSource = null;       
    Connection connection = null;
    String sql = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    long employeeId = -1;


    try {
        dataSourceLookupString = "java:comp/env/jdbc/chumbo";           
        initialContext = new InitialContext();
        dataSource = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup(dataSourceLookupString);
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        sql = "select top 1 employee_id from employee";
        statement = connection.createStatement();           
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);            
        if (resultSet != null && resultSet.next()) {
            employeeId = resultSet.getLong(1);
            System.out.println("testRetrieve(): employeeId=" + employeeId);
        }           
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
    }       
}
```

It did not work and I got this error:

> 2015-12-14 18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "EMPLOYEE" not found; SQL
>   statement: 2015-12-14 18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread
>   1-6) select top 1 employee_id from employee [42102-173] 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:331)
>   2015-12-14 18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)   at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:171) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:148) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4864) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1107) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1713)
>   2015-12-14 18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:1821) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1707) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1550) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1538) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:405) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,403 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279) 2015-12-14 18:54:50,419
>   ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251) 2015-12-14 18:54:50,419
>   ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)   at
>   org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:218) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,419 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:428) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,419 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:377) 2015-12-14
>   18:54:50,419 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)  at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1138)
>   2015-12-14 18:54:50,419 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)   at
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:72)
>   2015-12-14 18:54:50,419 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)   at
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedStatement.java:344)
>   2015-12-14 18:54:50,419 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-6)   at
>   com.z01.ejb.SLS01Bean.testRetrieve(SLS01Bean.java:197)

Now I change my code to lookup to JNDI Name directly:

```
dataSourceLookupString = "java:jboss/datasources/SchedulerDS";
```

And it worked perfect. So this means `jboss.xml` is not working in my case. How can I map a DataSource Resource Ref Name to a JNDI Name in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out that instead of `jboss.xml` I have to use `jboss-ejb3.xml` for WildFly.

Comment: In the jboss-ejb3.xml shema there is no <jndi-name> element, can you post the working file? I have the same problem but cannot get it working only renaming the file